# How do I change the label of a button in formtastic in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I tried the following and got an error:

```
11     = f.buttons, :label => "Create This"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
= f.buttons do
  = f.commit_button "Create This"
```

Answer (score 0):

Angela, remove the comma before the :label call. Hope that helps